# how to return IActionResult compatible UnprocessableEntity - HttpStatusCode (422)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.1

I want to return `IActionResult` compatible  `UnprocessableEntity - HttpStatusCode` (422) from below catch block the way I am returning `Ok' (200) from try block.

It's giving cast error for below code, What I can do here as I don't want to return 500.

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Net.HttpStatusCode' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult'

[image]

```
public IActionResult GetMe()
    {
        try
        {
            return Ok();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            //cast error

           // return HttpStatusCode.UnprocessableEntity;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just by intuition, by seeing that there already is an **Ok()** you should've realised there's an **UnprocessableEntity()** too ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want return this

```cs
public IActionResult GetMe()
    {
        try
        {
            return Ok();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            return UnprocessableEntity();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think this should be new UnprocessableEntityResult() just for clarity? (For .net core at least)